# Message sent to deallocated instance with ARC using custom getter and setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I'm trying to implement a custom getter and setter for my custom object `HFObject` and my app crashed with a `Message sent to deallocated instance` error despite using ARC.

I've read every single related post, the ones that were written pre-ARC don't apply, and everything else didn't help. I have the zombie object debugger option turned on.

---

### Setting up the custom HObject

Within HObject.h I have declared these four properties:

```
@property (retain) NSString *email;        //Will use custom getter/setter
@property (retain) NSString *firstName;    //Will use custom getter/setter
@property (retain) NSDate *date;           //Will use custom getter/setter
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *values;
```

In the implementation of HObject, I have removed the automatic getting and setting of `email`. `firstName`, and `date` by utilizing `@dynamic` like so

```
@dynamic email;
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic date;
```

I also allocate the `values`  dictionary in my HObject init

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.values = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    return self;
}
```

---

### Implementing Custom Getter & Sender

For my custom getter/setter. I have overridden

`- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector`

and

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
```

As shown below:

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSString *sel = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    if ([sel rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:@"];
    } else {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"@@:"];
    }
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
    if ([key rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) { 
        key = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [key length]-4)]; 

        id obj;   
        [invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];   

        [self.values setObject:obj forKey:key];
    } else {
        id obj = [self.values objectForKey:key];

        [invocation setReturnValue:&obj];
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is store all of the values of the property into my `values` dictionary and retrieve them from there as well.

---

### App Crashing

In the implementation of my view controller, I try to create a HObject and set values for my properties, and then I log the values dictionary to see all of my values.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    HObject *obj = [[HObject alloc] init];

    NSString *name = @"this is a string object";
    obj.date = [NSDate date];
    obj.email = @"email@website.com";
    obj.firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];


    NSLog(@"Values %@", [obj values]);
}
```

At that point the app crashes and this is my console log

```
2014-07-27 04:12:37.899 App[61501:60b] Values {
    Date = "2014-07-27 08:12:37 +0000";
    Email = "email@website.com";
    FirstName = "this is a string object";
}
2014-07-27 04:12:37.901 HeadsUp[61501:60b] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x109473fe0
```

If you can help me from here, I would greatly appreciate it. I am also including my debugging process in case that will help you

---

### My debugging Process (Long, skip if you can already help me)

I originally created many of these objects and stored them in an array, and when I do that, as opposed to creating a single object. my app crashed a bit different.

My array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
```

Methods:

```
- (void)createArray
{
    int i = 1; //number of testobjs

    NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:i];

    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
        HFObject *obj = [[User alloc] init];

        NSString *name = @"this is a string object";
        [obj setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Date"];
        obj.email = @"email@website.com";
        obj.firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];

        [objects addObject:obj];
    }


    self.array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];

}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    HObject *object = [self.array objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Values %@", [object values]);
}
```

Crash log:

```
2014-07-27 04:34:02.893 App[61623:60b] *** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1094988f0
(lldb)
```

Now this crash log is almost the same as the one before, except this didn't log the values inside of `[object values]`

Investigating the issue a bit, I looked at the left window (not sure what it is actually called) of the debugger and I saw this:

[image: ()]

(Treat `HFObject` as `HObject` and `dirtyValues` as `values`; I renamed them for presentational purposes)

You can see that under the key `@"FirstName"` there is no value.

I did several similar tests where I changed the values of the properties I was setting and changed the data types. More often than not, not only did `FirstName` not have a value, neither did `Date`. However, the value of email was always present.

After researching about dataTypes, I realized it was because `email` was a `string literal` which can't deallocated. On the other hand `firstName` and `date` were objects, which can be deallocated.

The crash log refers to a `CFString` property, which I learned doesn't use ARC. I never created a Core Foundation object, so I set out to found out it was being created in setter by logging the `[obj class]`:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
    if ([key rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) { 
        key = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [key length]-4)]; 

        id obj;   
        [invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];   

        NSLog(@"%@", [obj class]);  //I ADDED THIS LOG

        [self.values setObject:obj forKey:key];
    } else {
        id obj = [self.values objectForKey:key];

        [invocation setReturnValue:&obj];
    }
}
```

After crashing one more time, I got the `obj` classes

```
2014-07-27 04:58:03.893 HeadsUp[61765:60b] __NSDate
2014-07-27 04:58:03.894 HeadsUp[61765:60b] __NSCFConstantString
2014-07-27 04:58:03.894 HeadsUp[61765:60b] __NSCFString
2014-07-27 04:58:03.904 HeadsUp[61765:60b] *** -[__NSDate release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x109554370
(lldb)
```

Here you can see `Date` is being deallocated for some reason, and my string are now `__NSCF` strings.

I tried resetting the strings to `NSStrings` using `(__brigde NSString *)obj` and every other possible way you can bridge a CF object to ARC, however that didn't work either.

Here is everything I've done. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Why are you using method forwarding? That is now how you implement custom getters and setters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
id obj;   
[invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];
```

`getArgument` simply copies the object pointer into `obj` without retaining it.
However, since `obj` is (by default) a `__strong` variable, it will be released at
the end of the current method. To solve the problem, use

```
__unsafe_unretained id obj;   
[invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];
```

Note also that your getter implementation does not work. For example, `setFirstName:` 
stores the key in the dictionary using the key "FirstName", but the getter `firstName`
tries to read the value for the key "firstName".

(As already mentioned in a comment, it would probably easier and less error-prone
to just override the accessor methods for the three properties separately, instead
of dynamic forwarding.)

Comment: Also, I incorrectly renamed the firstName variable for this particular question. Everything matched up in the original project, so the getter worked. Once again, thanks