# Try get NSDate through forwardInvocation

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I have a problem.

I have method

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
SEL sel = anInvocation.selector;
NSString *prop = [self.class fieldNameForSelector:sel];
if (prop) {
    BOOL setter = [self isSetter:sel];
    __unsafe_unretained id obj;
    if (setter) {
        [anInvocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];
        [self setValue:obj forKey:prop];

    } else {
        obj = [self valueForKey:prop];
        [anInvocation setReturnValue:&obj];
    }
} else {
    [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}
```

}

But if I try to get object class NSDate or NSData it's doesn't work in 64-bit device. I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1`

And message from NSZombie

```
[__NSDate retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x171e00d50
```

But for another type object it works. How I can resolved this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` could deallocate right after assignment, because it's an `unsafe_unretained` reference, so `-setReturnValue:` gets dangling pointer as an argument.

If `unsafe_unretained` is unavoidable for setter path, (since `-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]` may not work properly with strong reference, thanks @Tommy for noting this), you could handle getter path differently, with strong reference.

Comment: I try do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979501/message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-with-arc-using-custom-getter-and-setter

Comment: @Nikolay from the answer posted, and from the documentation, it looks like `getArgument:atIndex:` doesn't retain object arguments, so if he weren't using `unsafe_unretained` then the compiler would blindly insert a release without that object having been retained. I think possibly the author's problem is that to avoid a problem there, he then handles the `valueForKey:` path incorrectly.